# I sent correct JSON format body from Postman to my Path but I get 400 Bad Request error

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, postman

I sent correct JSON Format body from Postman.

```
{
    "loginId": "xxxxxx",
    "password": "xxxxxx",
    "clientIP": "xxxxx",
    "companyId": "xxxxx"
}
```

This is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/umm")
   public class LoginServer {
       private transient Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
       @RequestMapping(value = "/basicLogin",method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public @ResponseBody LoginRequest login(@RequestBody(required = true) LoginRequest loginRequest){
           return null; 
}
```

}

And this is my domain

```
public class LoginRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -884241731093688658L;
    private String loginId;
    private String password;
    private String clientIP;
    private String companyId;

    public LoginRequest(String loginId, String password, String clientIP, String companyId) {
        this.loginId = loginId;
        this.password = password;
        this.clientIP = clientIP;
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

//getter and setter omitted

}
```

I don't know why it's return me 400 error code (Bad Request) because I sent a correct JSON body

This is Response message.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1549458416991,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of escf.api.domain.login.LoginRequest: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of escf.api.domain.login.LoginRequest: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1c360a55; line: 2, column: 2]",
    "path": "/umm/basicLogin"
}
```

I need it's return me code 200.

Comment: show the full request and the full response please, there schould be the error message

Comment: Ok you got it now.

Comment: Read the message in the response.  It tells you exactly what to fix.

Comment: I've created the exact same Controller and LoginRequest class and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I add super(); in domain class it's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

add super(); in domain class it's work.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using Jackson for serialization/deserialization instead of Gson, the following solution should work for you.

```
public class LoginRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -884241731093688658L;
    private String loginId;
    private String password;
    private String clientIP;
    private String companyId;

    @JsonCreator
    public LoginRequest(@JsonProperty("loginId") String loginId, @JsonProperty("password") String password, @JsonProperty("clientIP") String clientIP, @JsonProperty("companyId") String companyId) {
        this.setLoginId(loginId);
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.setClientIP(clientIP);
        this.setCompanyId(companyId);
    }

// Define your getters and setters IMPORTANT

}
```

Resources: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: Did you attempt to use my solution above? ^^^ Thanks.